# Adding a new column using other variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a new column named "league" to my sample data based on the names of the players clubs. Of course, my database consists of one thousand records.

**My data frame:**

```
df <- read.table(text= " Club       Player
                 'Real Madrid CF'     Ronaldo 
                 'FC Barcelona'       Messi 
                 'FC Bayern München'  Kross 
                 'Club Atlético de Madrid'  Torres
                 Juventus           Dybala
                 'Paris Saint-Germain'       Neymar",
                 header=TRUE)
```

**My idea:**

```
df$League <- ifelse(df$Club == "Real Madrid CF", "Spain",
                     ifelse(df$Club == "FC Barcelona", "Spain",
                     ifelse(df$Club == "Club Atlético de Madrid", "Spain",       
                     ifelse(df$Club == "Juventus", "Italy","Germany"))))
```

However, it is too time-consuming, I would also like to include *Na* for other players from outside these leagues.

Comment: I would create a key/val dataframe or a named vector to replace it once without any `ifelse` i.e. `df2 <- data.frame(Club = c("Real Madrid CF", "FC Barcelona", "Club Atlético de Madrid", "Juventus"), val = c("Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Italy"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and then do a `merge` or join i.e. `merge(df, df2, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: Or with `left_join` `library(dplyr); left_join(df, df2) %>% mutate(League  = replace(val, is.na(val), "Germany")) %>% select(-val)`

Comment: I do not know if this is a good idea, because I have a lot of data, it's best to create a vector made up of club names and then search through the columns of clubs only I do not know how to do it

Comment: It depends on how big the data is.  If it is around 40-60 gb, still `left_join` should be ok (given the memory is not a constraint).  but, if you have peta bytes of data, may be have to look for other tools

Answer (score 1):

We can create a named vector ('key/val') and then do the replacement by matching the keys with the 'Club' elements

```
df$League <- nm1[as.character(df$Club)]
df$League[is.na(df$League)] <- "Germany"
```

---

Or another option is to create a key/val dataset, do a `left_join`

#### data

```
nm1 <- structure(c("Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Italy"), 
  .Names = c("Real Madrid CF", 
 "FC Barcelona", "Club Atlético de Madrid", "Juventus"))
```

Comment: Let's assume I have 20 clubs from Spain, so what do you do not write 20 times Spain?

Comment: @Elia Yes, that is just an one time writing job.  May be you could use `rep` to replicate the strings.  Anyway, this would be much much efficient than using nested ifelse.  BTW, there is a limit for `ifelse` nesting.  It should be around 53 or so